# Why doesn't Android specify/check "sender" in sending Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

Except `startActivityForResult()`, the other interfaces for `Intent` exchanges (e.g., startService()) do not consider/check the "sender" component of the `Intent`.

What are advantages of not checking a "sender" of Intent? for security?

Comment: How do you know the sender is not checked?

Comment: I've looked at the Android source code.